# VS2010 toolbar takes too long to load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Each time that I open the VS2010 application, the toolbar seems to take ages to load (at least 10 minutes to load the toolbox on each application start). The status message at the bottom of the VS2010 screen displays:

```
Loading toolbox content from package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage'
```

I've got Telerik ASP.NET, Silverlight and WinForms controls added to my toolbox apart from the standard controls in Visual Studio.

Tried disabling AutoToolboxPopulate but that didn't help. Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Additional info:

- The toolbox is set to auto hide
- After the first 10 minute delayed load, the toolbox works fine during the rest of the time that I've got Visual Studio running.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This fix helped [Fixing a broken toolbox (In Visual Studio 2010 SP1) - Michael Crump](http://michaelcrump.net/fixing-a-broken-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1)

Comment: I had this whenever I opened a class diagram. It caused annoying waiting times. This fix worked perfectly! Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 2):

I Resolve the Problem by Move "Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.dll"
From
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
And Place It For Next Use to 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\bk

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look into the log? http://forums.silverlight.net/t/231462.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

There's a [Connect bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551183/loading-toolbox-content-from-package-takes-55-seconds-or-more) for this.  It's already closed, so you can't vote, but let Microsoft know you had the problem by clicking "I can too".